# How can I use JQuery slideDown to smoothly bring an image down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, slidedown, jquery-effects

I am using the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.some_class').slideDown(1000);
});
```

The code above works but the slideDown is sort of rough and jagged.  It's not smooth.  You can tell it's stuck for a few milliseconds.

What can I do for an easier slideDown effect?

I have a full page background image.  I am testing in firefox and chrome.

THe background image is loaded as part of a div in the body.  The div is the first thing after the body tag:

```
<div style="background-image:url('images/background.jpg');z-index:-2;position:fixed;height:100%;width:100%;display:none;" class="bg_load" id="bg"></div>


.bg_load:before {
    bottom: 0;
    content: "";
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.6;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
.bg_load:after {
    border-radius: 50% 50% 50% 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 0 300px 300px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
    content: "";
    height: 2px;
    left: 50%;
    margin: 200px 0 0 -1px;
    opacity: 1;
    position: fixed;
    top: 25%;
    transition: opacity 0.15s linear 0s;
    width: 2px;
}
.bg_load {
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-size: cover;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: fixed;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 100;
}
```

Comment: What browser are you testing with and how large is the image? Can you create an example at jsFiddle.net? From my experience .slideDown() works pretty well.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `$(window).load()` instead of `$(document).ready()` as `$(window).load()` will wait for images to finish loading before executing. This could be an issue if the image you're using is rather large and hasn't loaded before JQuery starts sliding down your image.

But more information in your question would really help solve this issue the best.

Comment: Think of replacing the deprecated - $(window).load(function(){...}); with $(window).on('load', function(){ ...});

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes trying to animate the image itself can be jerky if the image is large. If the browser has to re-render the image, then it's not going to be perfectly smooth.

You can try creating a container `div` for the image, set it to `overflow:hidden` and animate the height of the container. This works well with any content--not just images.

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    overflow:hidden;
    height:0px;
    width:220px;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg/220px-Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg">
</div>
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".container").animate({"height":"293px"},1000);
});
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/nyuz9/

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using jQuery to simply toggle a class, and handle the animation with a CSS3 transition. CSS3 leverages the power of the browser's hardware acceleration, so it's going to appear A LOT more smoothly.

I have forked ElliotB's example and provided example of the CSS transition. Pretty darn smooth, if I do say so myself.

[JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/AjWKs/1/)

**HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/e/eb/Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg/220px-Ash_Tree_-_geograph.org.uk_-_590710.jpg" />
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".container").addClass("visible");
});
```

**CSS**

```
.container {
  overflow:hidden;
  height:0px;
  width:220px;

  -webkit-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
     -moz-transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
          transition: height 1s ease-in-out;
}

.container.visible {
  height: 293px;
}
```

Comment: Transitions are great, but you'll run into browser support issues. All versions of IE below version 10 don't support transitions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition

Comment: Fair point. Perhaps CSS transitions for modern browsers, and JS fallback for older ones then?